# Can't see SSD hard disk after install Ubuntu 18.04 on HDD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

My XPS desktop has 1 TB M.2 PCle NVMe SSD + 2TB 7200RPM 3.5" SATA HDD hard disks. The Window system pre-install on the SSD, then I installed the Ubuntu on HDD, I don't want windows anymore, so I click 'erase disk and install ubuntu'. Then I check my disk through the "Disks" utility, it only shows HDD, I can't find SSD hard disk. anyone could help? Many thanks!

I tried sudo disk -l | grep sd, and these info showup:

Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors

/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System

/dev/sda2  1050624 3907028991 3905978368  1.8T Linux filesystem

Comment: Hi, I don't have a solution for you, but I would start by checking if the missing drive can be seen in BIOS? If yes, open terminal and run `sudo fdisk -l | grep sd` - can you see your drive in output of that command?

Comment: If an NVMe it will not show as sdX, but as /dev/nvme0n1. Many Dell need UEFI update & SSD update. And drives need to be AHCI in UEFI settings.

Comment: hi @kurja , thanks for your advice, the output shows: Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors

/dev/sda1 2048 1050623 1048576 512M EFI System

/dev/sda2 1050624 3907028991 3905978368 1.8T Linux filesystem

Comment: ok, so fdisk only finds your HDD (sda) like @oldfred said. Did you check your UEFI settings that the NVMe is set as AHCI like he suggested? I have no experience with hardware like yours and can't really help further than this unfortunately.

Comment: I changed the bios setting of SADA from REID to AHCI as @oldfred suggested, then I reinstalled the ubuntu on SSD, now I can see both, and HHD as a volume. Thank you so much for the help from you two!

Comment: @Vickyyyyyy that's great! You might now add the solution to your problem as an answer and mark it as accepted, that way others who might have the same problem can more easily find a solution to their issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the bios setting of SADA from REID to AHCI as oldfred suggested, then I reinstalled the ubuntu on SSD, now I can see both, and HHD as a volume.